# How to remove the gizmo perspective icon on the top right corner in Unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I want to turn off the display of the "persp icon" on the top right, you know, the one with the green, red, and blue conical arms.

Comment: May I ask you why? Is the Game View not enough?

Comment: @derHugo I'm using unity for storytelling videos, so I only need some screenshots from these packages, and because some of them can't run in the play mode, I have to get the screenshots from the scene interface; I've already gotten rid of all the other gizmos, but this one for me is just impossible to remove.

Comment: So basically the scene View is a camera that is moving through the scene and applying certain renderings ... so why not simply make a general take a screenshot of the SceneView camera?

Comment: You can hide Gizmos in general, by [clicking the Gizmo Button](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GizmosMenu.html) but I think the Orientation Tool is not affected by that. The hard way: Custom Editor Window, extending the Scene View, which hides the Orientation Tool - but a screenshot is a lot easier in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make a screenshot of the SceneView camera e.g. like ([source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/699856/programmatically-create-sceneview-screenshot.html))

```c#
/// <summary>
/// This adds an entry to the top main menu and a shortcut CTRL+ALT+S and stores files without transparency to Assets/{TimeStamp}.png
/// </summary>
[MenuItem("My Stuff/CaptureEditorScreenshot %&S")]
private static void CaptureEditorScreenshot()
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd-hh_mm_ss") + ".png");

    CaptureEditorScreenshot(path);
}

public static void CaptureEditorScreenshot(string filePath)
{
    var sw = SceneView.lastActiveSceneView;

    if (!sw)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unable to capture editor screenshot, no scene view found");

        return;
    }

    var cam = sw.camera;

    if (!cam)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unable to capture editor screenshot, no camera attached to current scene view");

        return;
    }

    var renderTexture = cam.targetTexture;

    if (!renderTexture)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Unable to capture editor screenshot, camera has no render texture attached");

        return;
    }

    var width = renderTexture.width;
    var height = renderTexture.height;

    var outputTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;

    cam.Render();

    outputTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);

    var pngData = outputTexture.EncodeToPNG();

    UnityEngine.Object.DestroyImmediate(outputTexture);

    RenderTexture.active = null;

    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, pngData);

    AssetDatabase.Refresh();

    Debug.Log("Screenshot written to file " + filePath);
}
```

Afaik by default this ignores all handles, grids, gizmos and in specific also that top-right scene view handle. It just renders the content as if it would look in the GameView.

[image]

**Note**: Make sure to either put this in a folder called `Editor` or add according `#if UNITY_EDITOR` pre-processors around it since [`SceneView`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneView.html) is in the `UnityEditor` namespace. You said you never build that project anyway but you know just in case and also for other readers ;)

Comment: This scene can't be played (nor can a lot of others), so can this method still work, or it can only capture the screen in the play mode?

Comment: As you can see in the gif at the bottom I'm calling it just from the editor without play mode ;)

Comment: It didn't do what I wanted (doesnt capture the different modes like wireframe) but it works like a charm otherwise. I might just add that you need to wrap the above code in a class, and add these namespaces:
using System.DateTime;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the 3 dots on the top right corner opens a drop down menu,inside the first option "overlays" you can check on or off the "orientation" option.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWwlZ.gif